# ORACLE NOT NULL IN WHERE CLAUSE WITH NVL OPERATION

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I want to know which query is faster.

ex:1

```
select comm
from emp
where comm is not null;
```

ex:2

```
select comm
from emp
where nvl(comm,'0') is not null;
```

Please consider the EMP table contains hundreds of thousands of records.

Comment: The two statements do different things.  You should run the query that does what you want, not merely the fastest.

Comment: What does lakhs mean?

Comment: Just an example for lakhs of records

Comment: @BobC - [hundreds of thousands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh). Which is still a pretty trivial amount these days.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of asking a hypothetical question you should run some benchmarks on your actual data. But here are some observations:

Your queries do different things. Your first query selects all the records where COMM is not null. Your second query selects all the records.

In both cases it will probably be two Full Table Scans: " lakhs of records." makes no difference. However, given that they have the same projection and no sort clause the execution time will be the same.

Except:

1. The time to render the output will be different, because the second
   result set may be larger than the first.
2. If there is an index on
   `EMP(COMM)` the first result will probably use a Full Fast Index Scan,
   because you're only selecting `COMM` so there's no need to touch the
   table. An index read would be faster because normal Oracle indexes don't index nulls.
3. Even if there's a function-based index on `EMP(NVL(COMM))` the
   second query will still execute a Full Table Scan, because you 
   select `COMM` in the projection so the query still needs to read the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your two queries do different things.  The first gets non-NULL values.  The first pulls everything.

I think you intend:

```
select comm from emp where comm is not null;

select comm from emp where nvl(comm, '0') <> '0'
```

These still do different things, because the second also filters out "natural" `'0'` values.  But they are much closer.

The first is simpler and uses one built-in operator.  The second runs a function and uses the same built-in operator.  The first should never be slower than the second -- with one exception.

Oracle allows indexes on expressions.  If you happen to have an index on `nvl(comm, '0')` *and* most values are '0' *and* you don't have an index on `comm`, then the second would use the index and would be faster.